# wrapping Child element into UL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Navigation Based on xslt and and it out puts following XML

```
    <Page ID="19" AreaID="1" MenuText="Language Selector" Href="Default.aspx?ID=19" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/language-selector.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="3" RelativeLevel="3" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="2" class="L3" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True">
      <Page ID="20" AreaID="1" MenuText="DK" Href="Default.aspx?ID=20" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/language-selector/dk.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="4" RelativeLevel="4" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L4" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
      <Page ID="21" AreaID="1" MenuText="NO" Href="Default.aspx?ID=21" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/language-selector/no.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="4" RelativeLevel="4" Sort="2" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L4" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
    </Page>

    <Page ID="27" AreaID="1" MenuText="Quicklinks" Href="Default.aspx?ID=27" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/quicklinks.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="3" RelativeLevel="3" Sort="2" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="2" class="L3" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True">
      <Page ID="17" AreaID="1" MenuText="Tool 1" Href="Default.aspx?ID=17" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/quicklinks/tool-1.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="4" RelativeLevel="4" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L4" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
      <Page ID="18" AreaID="1" MenuText="Tool 2" Href="Default.aspx?ID=18" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/quicklinks/tool-2.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="4" RelativeLevel="4" Sort="2" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L4" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
    </Page>
```

Desired Out from this Should be something like this

```
<ul>
  <li><a>DK</a></li>
  <li><a>NO</a><li>
</ul>
<ul> 
   <li><a>Tool 1</a><li> 
   <li><a>Tool 2</a><li> 
</ul>
```

Following is my XSLT Code I have tried so far

```
    <xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">
    <xsl:if test="count(//Page) > 0">
      <div class="container">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
          <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Page">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
      <li>
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:if test="count(Page)">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
              <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </ul>
        </xsl:if>
      </li>

  </xsl:template>
```

Please Help Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

If I change your first template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">
    <xsl:if test="count(//Page) > 0">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
                    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="1" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and surround your xml with

```
<Navigation>...</Navigation>
```

then I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/language-selector.aspx">Language Selector</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/language-selector/dk.aspx">DK</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/language-selector/no.aspx">NO</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/quicklinks.aspx">Quicklinks</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/quicklinks/tool-1.aspx">Tool 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/da-dk/globalelements/toolsnavigation/quicklinks/tool-2.aspx">Tool 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which is quite what you like, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

In your Page template, you can use a `<xsl:choose>` to specify what happens when `depth` has a certain value:

```
<xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">
    <xsl:if test="count(//Page) > 0">
        <div class="container">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
                <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//Page">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$depth = 1 and count(Page)">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
                    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <li>
                <a>
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </a>
              </li>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This should produce the desired output.